# ModelView in BottomSheetFragment

Tags: android

I am building an application where I want to show a bottomSheetFragment in the MainActivity. Since I am showing some data in that fragment (user account details etc.), I decided that the best way to achieve that is use a modelView.

So, I set the data in the main activity as shown here :

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // Initialize view model for bottom menu.
    bottomMenuData = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BottomMenuData.class);
    bottomMenuData.setGoogleSignInAccount(CurrentGmailAccount);
    ...
}
```

Now, I observe value changed in my bottomSheetFragment as shown here :

```
// Observe google account.
bottomMenuData.getGoogleSignInAccount().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), googleSignInAccount -> {
    // Load image.
    Glide.with(account_image)
         .load(googleSignInAccount.getPhotoUrl())
         .apply(new RequestOptions()
         .placeholder(R.drawable.sample_image_profile))
         .into(account_image);

         // Set other account details.
         account_name.setText(googleSignInAccount.getDisplayName());
         account_email.setText(googleSignInAccount.getEmail());
});
```

I try to initialize viewModel like this :

```
@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    bottomMenuData = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(BottomMenuData.class);
    super.onAttach(context);
}
```

The problem is that I get an exception here that say I try to get activity before onCreateView(). Lifecycle for fragment says that onAttach is ran after onCreateView(). I tried to initialize viewModel onViewCreated() too but code never executes there! I have read almost whole internet for that but could not make it work!

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:
This is the source code for my viewModel :

```
public class DataModel extends ViewModel {
    /** The current gmail account. */
    private MutableLiveData<GoogleSignInAccount> currentGmailAccount = new MutableLiveData<>();
    /** List containing messages history. */
    private MutableLiveData<List<MsgModel>> messagesList = new MutableLiveData<>();
    /** Listener to invoke callbacks for item clicks. */
    private MutableLiveData<SettingsListener> settingsListener = new MutableLiveData<>();
    /** Defines if it is the first run (first onCreate). */
    boolean firstRun = true;

    /**
     * Add a new message to messages list.
     * @param message Message to add.
     */
    void AddMessage(MsgModel message) {
        // Make sure list is initialized.
        if (messagesList.getValue() == null) messagesList.setValue(new ArrayList<>());

        // Add new message.
        messagesList.getValue().add(message);
    }

    /**
     * Defines how many messages are in the messages list.
     * @return The count of the messages in the messages list.
     */
    int MessagesSize() {
        // Make sure list is initialized.
        if (messagesList.getValue() == null) messagesList.setValue(new ArrayList<>());

        return  messagesList.getValue().size();
    }

    /**
     * Get current gmail account as set from {@Link MainActivity}.
     * @return Current gmail account. May be null if requested before set.
     */
    GoogleSignInAccount GetCurrentGmailAccount() {
        return currentGmailAccount.getValue();
    }

    @NonNull
    public MutableLiveData<GoogleSignInAccount> GetGoogleSignInAccount() {
        return currentGmailAccount;
    }

    void SetGoogleSignInAccount(GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount) {
        this.currentGmailAccount.setValue(googleSignInAccount);
    }

    @NonNull
    public SettingsListener GetSettingsListener() {
        return settingsListener.getValue();
    }

    void SetSettingsListener(SettingsListener settingsListener) {
        this.settingsListener.setValue(settingsListener);
    }

    @NonNull
    MutableLiveData<List<MsgModel>> GetMessagesList() {
        // Make sure list is initialized.
        if (messagesList.getValue() == null) messagesList.setValue(new ArrayList<>());

        return messagesList;
    }
}
```

Comment: post your BottomMenuData class

Comment: It is a simple class that extends ViewModel. Nothing special in this class. In the mainActivity it works like a charm. I can set value in the model. The problem is I can not figure out how to make it work in the BottomSheetFragment class.

Comment: Are you setting value in livedata inside setGoogleSignInAccount(CurrentGmailAccount) method?

Comment: Current account is set from MainActivity and fragment is just observing for data changes on this account. Observer is used to update account settings on a view in the dialog.

Comment: I understand buddy :). just post your view model class . I guess you are not setting value to livedata.

Comment: Okay, editted my post and added source code of viewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getActivity() can be null while your fragment is in process of preparation and about to be ready. Move your ViewModel reference/instance creation into [onActivityCreated][1]

[1]: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle), like below,

```
void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    bottomMenuData = 
ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(BottomMenuData.class);

}
```

Comment: Well, after 2 days trying to figure this out, this was so easy at all :) Thank you very much sir! You made my day!!